# Vue JS : Wait firebase to load

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I want to use firebase inside a Vue JS component, but it seems like the firebase object is loaded after the creation of my component.

Is there a way to wait for firebase to load before executing JS code ?

Exemple : i want to create a vue composant called loader which output the firebase object on the webconsole at his creation

```
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Firebase -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/5.0.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<!-- Vue.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
<script>
var loader =  {
    template: '<div></div>',
    created: function(){
        console.log(window.firebase); // undefined
    }
};
var app = new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    template : 
        `<div>
            <loader></loader>
        </div>`,
    components : {
        'loader' : loader
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work but, of course, one second later i can output the firebase object on the console.

PS :

- It is my first question on this website so if you have any advice on how to ask question, i will take it as well.
- I am french so pardon my english

Comment: Load firebase before your Vue scripts.

Comment: My Vue script is loaded just at the end of the body section while the firebase script is loaded inside the head section of my html file

Comment: Is the window.firebase ever set then? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Vue is probably completely irrelevant in this question. Firebase should be accessible in any script that's below the firebase script. Post the relevant code, which is how you're loading firebase.

Comment: Let me some time, i will edit my post to clarify my exemple

Comment: It's caused by those defer attributes, the current example is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the [defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attributes from the firebase scripts. It will cause the scripts to be executed once the whole document has been parsed, which means that your script in the body runs before firebase scripts.

Comment: How to remove defer?